# Is this possible to write list of file names into a text file using batch file Windows Xp?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to write the list of file names from a Given directory path in to text file whenever clicking a windows XP batch file.I don't know whether it is possible or not in Windows Xp?

So,Can u please enlighten me on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file to list all files in a dir in windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847302/batch-file-to-list-all-files-in-a-dir-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
dir /b "C:\My Path" > myFiles.txt
```

Comment: :It can also retreive the directory name inside it.How can i avoid it?

Comment: If you mean you want to show only files and not directories, add `/a-d` (attribute type of "not directories").  See `dir /?` for all of the available options.

Comment: @ Ziesemer: Is this possible to write file names in ascending order?

Comment: Please read the documentation provided by `dir /?`.  Though to answer your question, yes - add `on` ("order by name").

Comment: This doesn't work very well with accented characters.

Comment: Note that `/s` is incompatible with `/a -d` - it will produce `File not found` if you combine them.

Answer (score 0):

In a detailed way

```
@echo off
Rem Following command will write the names of all files in a text file
dir "C:\Source folder" > C:\destination.txt
echo "File names have been written"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list down all the file names with other details like time/size etc and no other directory information, you can use the below command

```
DIR c:\temp\*.* | FIND ":" > logfile.txt
```

This will obtain a bare `DIR` format (no heading or footer info) but retain all the details, pipe the output of `DIR` into `FIND`.
This assumes that your date time stamp separator is `:` (e.g. `09-04-2018  11:06`).