# Batch file to list all files in a dir in windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to list all the files in a directory and then write that to a text file using a batch file. I think it should be something like

```
dir / (some flags here) >> files.txt
```

which will contain a listing like

```
a.exe
b.exe
c.exe
```

etc. etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the `/b` switch (to write file list only, without header and other informations).

```
dir /b >> list.txt
```

Then if you need to list all `.exe` files in `c:\windows` the full command is:

```
dir c:\windows\*.exe /b >> list.txt
```

Please note that `>>` will **append** the list to the file. Do not forget you can use multiple search patterns, for example:

```
dir *.jpg;*.png /b > list.txt
```

It'll write all the `.jpg` and `.png` files (only names, without path or any other informations) to the file `list.txt` (overwriting the file if it did exist before).

If you need to exclude directories you can rely on `/a` switch (to include/exclude items according to an attribute). In your case you want to exclude directories then you have to use `-d`:

```
dir /b /a-d >> list.txt
```

Finally do not forget `dir` can be used recursively with `/s` switch (to list files that match search pattern in the given directory and in all sub-directories) and sorted with `/o` option. Use `dir /?` for more details about that.

Comment: Is there some way to exclude directory listings from this?

Comment: @Damien.Bell yes, you can use the /A switch to include/exclude files with a given attribute (D for directories). In your case use /A-D to exclude all directories.

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much have it down already.
if you are only wanting to list the files in that directory then

```
dir /A-D >> somefile.txt
```

OR

```
dir /A-D > somefile.txt    

dir /
```

- `>>` appends
- `>` creates new or overwrites existing

  dir /A-D /ON > somefile.txt

This will sort by name.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
dir C:\ /s /b >files.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use tree for recursive list files in directory tree

and for dumping to text file you can use this:

> C:\tree "D:\my directory" > "D:\dump file.txt"