# Exclude files from being downloaded

Tags: shell, batch-file, synchronization, server

Im using a server. Id like to sync files with my home PC. Unfortunally there is no app that could remember what files was previously downloaded - so if the file is moved from the "incoming" folder, it will be redownloaded from the server.

Ive found a app (goodsync) that is able to run a script or batch pre-download. So I was thinking, Ill run a script in advance that writes all the filenames to a .txt according this -> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612324/is-this-possible-to-write-list-of-file-names-into-a-text-file-using-batch-file-w`

So, how to script or batch something like "check what´s in C:\exclude.txt and dont download files with the exact same name"

Comment: Hey @Jan, I would not use the names for this. I would use a combination of name and hash.

Comment: If you can tell me how, this would be a nice idea ;) I know that this can all be done with rsync and a cron (the server runs cent OS) but this is far over my head...

Comment: Do you use Linux or Windows? I could give you tips for a shell script but I can't tell you how to do this on windows (Assumed you use Windows because of "C:\exclude.txt")

Comment: Home pc where the files should be transfered to is Win, Server is a CentOS

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's a little shell script which can be used to read which files are already downloaded, reads which files exist and then checks which files should be downloaded. But I recommend you to learn shell scripting to understand the script and to make the script better.

Basically what this code does is reading the downloaded.txt (or exclude.txt) file (Every line should containt filename and hash concatenated).
Then it reads all files from the file system and checks if the file is contained in the downloaded.txt file.

If the file is not contained in the downloaded.txt file you can decide what you would like to do.

- you could create a new textfile which contains the files you have to
  download.
- you could add the files found to downloaded.txt (but use the searched variable because it contains the hash and the filename) and download these files.

```
    found=0
    array_contains () { 
        local array="$1[@]"
        local seeking=$2
        found=0
        for element in "${!array}"; do
            if [[ $element == $seeking ]]; then
            found=1
            break
            fi
        done
    }


    downloaded_files=()

    #Load the downloaded files from downloaded.txt into the downloaded_files array
    old_IFS=$IFS      # save the field separator           
    IFS=$'\n'     # new field separator, the end of line           
    for line in $(cat downloaded.txt)          
    do          
       downloaded_files=("${downloaded_files[@]}" "$line")          
    done          


    #print the whole array just for testing
    echo ${downloaded_files[@]}


    filehashlist=($(find * -type f -exec sha1sum "{}" \; | cut -d ' ' -f 1))
    filenamelist=($(find * -type f -exec basename "{}" \;))
    filenamelistFullPath=($(find * -type f))


    to_download_files=()
    counter=0
    for filename in "${filenamelist[@]}"
    do
        searched=$filename${filehashlist[$counter]}
        array_contains downloaded_files "$searched"
        if [ $found == "0" ]; then
            echo "Please download file: $filename"
            echo "Location: ${filenamelistFullPath[$counter]}"
            echo "Hash: ${filehashlist[$counter]}"
            echo "Add this line to downloaded.txt after download: $searched"        
            echo ""
        fi
        counter=$counter+1
    done

    IFS=$old_IFS     # restore default field separator
```

Comment: Dumb, but this shell should be saved as .bat and then executed? Please talk to me like im doing shell for the first time....

Comment: no you save it as name.sh and run it with ./name.sh in linux on console.

Comment: maybe im just missing the point... but how do i get a windows app to run a shell?

Comment: Edit: The download.txt is on the windows pc, as the sync program is started in windows as well. So it "gets" files instead of "sending" from the server.

Answer (score 0):

From command line or .CMD script:

```
xcopy /D /E /F /Y /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt
```

where exclude.txt is the file you mentioned containing your list of filenames to be excluded